# Do child routes require the same params as all other routes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I can currently route to `engagementGeneral` path, but if I want to route back to `landing`, I tried `:to="{ name: 'landing'}` but the browser spits out missing required param `engagementNum`.

I got around this by using `:to="{ name: 'landing', params: { engagementNum: 'none' } }"`

But obviously this isn't correct. How to I navigate to a path when the current path requires a param?

```
{
    path: "/",
    component: () => import("layouts/MainLayout.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        name: "landing",
        path: "",
        component: () => import("pages/Landing.vue"),
      },
      {
        name: "engagement",
        path: "engagement/:engagementNum",
        component: () => import("pages/ProjectInfo.vue"),
        children: [
          {
            name: "engagementGeneral",
            path: "general",
            component: () =>
              import("components/DetailsPages/EngagementInfo/GeneralInfo.vue"),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

**`params` are ignored if a `path` is provided, which is not the case for `name` or `query`. So with using `path` instead of `name` in your :to="{}, you dont have to provide a param.**

(The problems with params is because they are nested. You could take a look and consider if you really need to have Landing as a child here, if restructuring is an option for you.
There is also an option to add a `?` In the end path: `"engagement/:engagementNum?”` if having an optional parameter is a valid solution for you.)

Comment: Awesome using `:to="{ path: '/' }"` worked great thanks! Also I made the param optional. Super helpful!

I'm inheriting the mainLayout, using the header on the Landing page. I don't know if it's the best way of doing it, but it's working for me.